Unexpected end of script running Big Query
I am getting the syntax error "unexpected end of script at 13:4" when I try to run the first part of my Big Query.
Please see query below.
WITH
  longest_used_bike as (
    SELECT
      bike_id, 
      SUM(duration_minutes) AS trip_duration
    FROM 
      bigquery-public-data.austin_bikeshare.bikeshare_trips
    GROUP BY
      bike_id
    ORDER BY
      trip_duration DESC
    LIMIT 1
  )

I have double checked and I need to know what the problem is.

I dont bigquery, but if this is a CTE as in other SQL products you should select from it. I.e. WITH longest_used_bike as ( ... ) select * from longest_used_bike

the use of CTE has nothing to do with temporary tables. CTE is just a way to factorize a query as a subquery and give a name to simplify the writing of the global query. The CTE did not produce a temporary table. temporay table in ISO standard SQL is created by the command CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ...

You've made a CTE instead of a plain query, but done nothing with it.

just use the CTE after and it will work.  add this after....select * from longest_used_bike

I think you get that error because the column trip_duration doesn't exist. We can change ORDER BY as below:
WITH longest_used_bike as ( 
    SELECT bike_id, SUM(duration_minutes) AS trip_duration 
    FROM bigquery-public-data.austin_bikeshare.bikeshare_trips 
    GROUP BY bike_id 
    ORDER BY SUM(duration_minutes)
    DESC LIMIT 1 
)

And you are using Common Table Expression (CTE). You can view the link to see its differences from temp table.
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/common-table-expression-cte-vs-temporary-sql-server-amr-saafan/
Hope it helps !

try this
WITH
  longest_used_bike AS (
    SELECT
      bike_id, 
      SUM(duration_minutes) AS trip_duration
    FROM 
      bigquery-public-data.austin_bikeshare.bikeshare_trips
    GROUP BY
      bike_id
    ORDER BY
      trip_duration DESC
    LIMIT 1
  )
SELECT *
FROM longest_used_bike;

